# Actioning styling and a tooltipster on a dynamically created select2 element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, tooltipster

I have a page partly dynamically created with some select2 elements being returned from an ajax call. I then need to do some jquery on it to manipulate it. The page is a bit complex as it displays forms in a table, each row being one form.

What I want to do is render a red colored border and a tooltipster when no data is typed in the select2 element. The select2 field is required and it should display a user error message as no data is typed in. There are several such  select2 elements on the page and none of them display any tooltipster. Other non-select2 fields do display their tooltipster.

With some console loggers, I can see that the error message data to be fed to the tooltipster is coming back from the form submission. I can also see the tooltipster object is seen by jquery. But it just won't display and it won't get colored in red.

In the successful property of the ajax call to save one row of data:

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(result['messages']['success'])) {
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(result['messages']['client_id'])) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(result['messages']['client_id'], function( index, value ) {
      html += ' ' + value;
    });
    displayError('#clients[' + maxLevel + ']-' + id, html);
    displayError('#client_id-' + id, html);
  }
  for (j = 0; j <= maxLevel; j++) {
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(result['messages']['clients[' + j + ']'])) {
      var html = '';
      $.each(result['messages']['clients[' + j + ']'], function( index, value ) {
        html += ' ' + value;
      });
console.log($('[name^="clients[' + j + ']-'+id+'"]'));
console.log(html);
      displayError('[name^="clients[' + j + ']-'+id+'"]', html);
      displayError('#clients[' + j + ']-' + id, html);
      displayError('#client_id-' + id, html);
    }
  }
```

The functions to display the error:

```
function displayError(id, html) {
   $(id).css('border-color', 'red');
   $(id).attr('title', html);
   displayTooltipster(id);
}

function displayTooltipster(id) {
  if (!$(id).hasClass("tooltipstered")) {
    $(id).tooltipster({
      position: 'top-left',
      contentAsHTML: 'true',
      theme: '.tooltipster-default',
      animation: 'grow'
    });
  } else {
    $(id).tooltipster('enable');
  }
}
```

The console loggers have this to display:

```
[input#clients[0]-212713.form-control.input-small.tooltipster.select2-offscreen, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "[name^="clients[0]-212713"]"]
vehicule-realocate:554  Une valeur est requise et ne peut être vide
vehicule-realocate:553 
[input#clients[1]-212713.form-control.input-small.tooltipster.select2-offscreen, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "[name^="clients[1]-212713"]"]
vehicule-realocate:554  Une valeur est requise et ne peut être vide
vehicule-realocate:553
```

On each row, there are several select2 fields; each being displayed in a chained fashion, the next one replacing the previous one, allowing the selection of nodes in a tree. This works just fine and allows me to navigate the tree of nodes:

```
function handleSelect2Fields() {
    for (var i=0; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
        var el = $('[name^="clients[' + i + ']"]');
        el.data('level', i);
        el.select2({
            width: 'element',
            ajax: {
                url: '<?php echo $this->url('users/get-client-options'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function(term, page) {
                    var level = parseInt(this.data('level'));
                    if (level > 0) {
                        var sameRowClients = $(this).parent().parent();
                        var oneClientFromSameRow = sameRowClients.find('[name^="clients[' + (level-1) + ']"]');
                        var el = oneClientFromSameRow;
                        return {client_id : el.val(), term : term}
                    }
                },
                results: function(data, page) {
                    data.datas.push({'id':0, 'text':'[Retour]'});
                    return {results : data.datas, more : false}
                }
            },
            initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            }
        });
        el.on('change', function(e) {
          var selectedValue = e.val;
            var level = parseInt($(this).data('level'));
            if (selectedValue == 0) {
              if (level > 0) {
                level -= 1;
              }
            } else {
              level += 1;
            }
            for (var i=0; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
                var sameRowClients = $(this).parent().parent();
                var oneClientFromSameRow = sameRowClients.find('[name^="clients[' + i + ']"]');
                var el = oneClientFromSameRow;
                if (i == level) {
                  oneClientFromSameRow.parent().show();
                    el.select2("val", '');
                    el.select2("readonly", false);
                    el.select2("open");
                } else if (i < level && level <= maxLevel) {
                  oneClientFromSameRow.parent().hide();
                } else if (i > level) {
                  oneClientFromSameRow.parent().hide();
                    el.select2("readonly", true);
                    el.select2("val", '');
                }
            }
            var id_suffix = oneClientFromSameRow.attr('id').split('-')[1];
            if (level > maxLevel) {
                $('[name=client_id-' + id_suffix + ']').val($(this).val());
            } else {
                $('[name=client_id-' + id_suffix + ']').val('');
            }
            $('[name=client_id-' + id_suffix + ']').val($(this).val());
        });
        if (i != 0) {
            if (! el.val()) {
              el.select2("readonly", true);
              $('[name^="clients[' + i + ']"]').parent().hide();
            }
        }
    }

function loadItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->url('ajax', array('action' => 'get-vehicules-to-realocate'));?>",
        data: {'maxLevel': maxLevel},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(items) {
            $.each(items['html'], function(id, contentHtml) {
                $('#list-items').append(contentHtml);
            });

            $('#nb_items').html(items['total']);
            $('#header').html(items['header']);

            $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 'dateFormat': 'yy-mm-dd'});

            handleSelect2Fields();
        }
    });
}
```

On the server side, some markup is generated to render the select2 elements:

```
$client = '<input type="hidden" name="client_id-' . $id . '" id="client_id-' . $id . '" value="" class="tooltipster">';
for ($j = 0; $j <= $maxLevel; $j++) {
  $client .= '<span><input type="hidden" name="clients[' . $j . ']-' . $id . '" id="clients[' . $j . ']-' . $id . '" value="" class="form-control input-small tooltipster" required></span>';
}
```

The client fields are inside a bootstrap table:

```
$html[$i] = '<div class="row" id="bloc-' . $id . '">'
    . '<div class="span1" style="text-align:center; white-space:nowrap;">' . $client . '</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way around this issue was to traverse the DOM tree up by two parents so as to reach some enclosing div.

The method being use to display the error message now uses two `parent()` calls:

```
function displaySelect2Error(id, html) {
   $(id).parent().parent().css('border', 'solid 1px');
   $(id).parent().parent().css('border-color', 'red');
   $(id).parent().parent().attr('title', html);
   displayTooltipster($(id).parent().parent());
}
```

And it is being called like:

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(result['messages']['success'])) {
  for (j = 0; j <= maxLevel; j++) {
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(result['messages']['clients[' + j + ']'])) {
      var html = '';
      $.each(result['messages']['clients[' + j + ']'], function( index, value ) {
        html += ' ' + value;
      });
      displaySelect2Error('#client_id-' + id, html);
    }
  }
```